# Revert changes and delete user files after boot

Tags: windows-10

For years we're still looking for some kind of a free reboot-restore solution on six Windows 10 clients. We are a non-profit organization.. Imagine an internet cafe environment, browser history, user modifications and so on should not be saved upon reboot. Updates should go on, automatically as much as possible (Don't mind to update manually on patch Tuesday, eventually). If it requires a main set-up or a lot of maintenance, naming them will be appreciated for the clear picture.

We already tried:
Reboot Restore RX (breaks windows update, bsod, troubles)
Time Freeze (breaks windows update, bsod, troubles)
Deep Freeze Trial (my employer don't want to spend money, but it works...)

Anyone tips?

Kind Regards,
Lajos

Comment: Any help at  https://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/?license=free&platform=windows or https://alternative.me/deep-freeze ? If so, let us now and I - or you - can post an answer, which will help others who read this question in future. I hope that some of those will help ... Good luck :-)

Comment: I reviewed alternativeto multiple times as well. Experience means more.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I feel that way too. It is just about receptacle to recommend alternative sites, but not - IMO - to jst google; not as a comment, and certainly not as an answer. Good luck. If you do find an answer, please post here.

Comment: Just wondering to opinions or ideas. Haha.